# rds export to s3 object prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Have a daily process that's been exporting snapshots from rds to s3.

The structure of s3 objects used to look like this:
`my-bucket/my-prefix/my-table/part-XXXX` etc.

However, since a couple of days, it's been doing creating the following:
`my-bucket/my-prefix/my-table/1/part-XXXX`

Does anyone know where's this `/1/` coming from?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score -1):

I have checked the documentation and here's the culprit:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html#USER_ExportSnapshot.FileNames

Under file naming convention.